# AMD64 Assembly: Correctly returning a float from function

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, calling-convention

As a learning exercise/small project i am writing a simple compiler.
This is the source code i am compiling (my own language):

```
fn: main(arg: float) ~ float {
    return arg * 4.0;
}
```

As seen, this function takes a float, and returns the multiplication with 4 as result.
This is assuming the default calling convention on x64 linux, in which float arguments get passed and returned in the xmm-registers. The code currently compiles down to the following:

```
pushq  %rbp
movq   %rsp, %rbp
subq   $0x4, %rsp ; increment stack
movss  %xmm0, 0x4(%rsp) ; and save the float argument
subq   $0x4, %rsp 
movl   0x8(%rsp), %r11d ; expressions copy their parameters. this is what happens here
movl   %r11d, 0x4(%rsp)
subq   $0x4, %rsp
movb   $0x0, 0x4(%rsp) ; inefficient: but my compiler loads the float
movb   $0x0, 0x3(%rsp) ; byte-by-byte here
movb   $-0x80, 0x2(%rsp)
movb   $0x40, 0x1(%rsp)
flds   0x8(%rsp) ; load the floats
flds   0x4(%rsp)
fmulp  %st, %st(1); multiply
subq   $0x4, %rsp ; increment space for the result
fsts   0x4(%rsp) ; store it on the stack
movl   0x4(%rsp), %r11d
movl   %r11d, 0xc(%rsp) ; copy the return value to the start of this expressions stack frame
addq   $0x8, %rsp
movss  0x4(%rsp), %xmm0  ; copy the float on the top of the stack frame to the xmm0 register
addq   $0x8, %rsp ; pop the entire stackframe
popq   %rbp
retq ; return
```

Please excuse the long batch of assembly - my compiler produces very unoptimized code. i commented a bit for clarity.
Now - the above code *works*... But it produces a bogus result. It basically always returns
a bogus float value. And i dont understand as to why - provided i correctly understood the SysV-ABI, this should work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first `movss` already looks suspicious; it's overwriting the pushed `rbp` on the stack.  The stack pointer always points to the object most recently pushed, so I think this should be `movss %xmm0, (%rsp)`.  And most of the rest of your stack handling seems similarly off.  On the other hand, it's really best to keep the stack pointer aligned to 8 bytes at all times.

Comment: You store your `4.0` into `1..4(%rsp)` instead of `0..3(%rsp)` and then you don't even load it.

Comment: `main` has to return an `int` in normal systems, and gets `int` and `char*` args, unless your startup code is very different from C environments.  Calling your function anything else would be less surprising.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping this with your assembly-level debugger, inspecting the stack and registers as you go?  I think that'll be very instructive.

Comment: Not to mention that constant isn't even `4.0` because you messed up the endianness.

Comment: Your compiler output would be easier to debug if it wasn't so anti-optimized.  e.g. reserve all the stack space you'll need at the top of the function.  Even TCC (the Tiny C compiler which compiles in *one pass* through the C source and the machine code output) works that way, emitting a boilerplate function prologue which it seeks back to fill in with an immediate for `sub` once it gets to the end of the function.  I know people say correctness before performance, but you know you're going to want your asm output to suck this badly, so maybe spend a little more time on stack-frame layout.

Comment: You can leave using `push imm32` for later, if you do want to grow your stack frame while evaluating a constant.  Note that normally you'd put `dd 4.0` in the `.rodata` section (static storage) instead of using a mov-immediate.  Also, if you're making a compiler for x86-64, use XMM registers in the first place instead of messing around with legacy x87.  Mixing x87 and SSE just makes everything harder, uglier, and slower.  The calling convention uses SSE so it makes sense to go that way.  `mulss` is easy to use.

Comment: Hello All! Thanks for the feedback. This isnt my first time writing a compiler, but im pretty new with x86 assembly. The code works now - the issue was that i had switched up in a particular spot: Instead of copying the result of the "arg * 4.0" to the top of the stackframe, i copied the top down to the bottom of the frame.

Comment: The intended usecase for now is as an embedded, JIT-compiled scripting language. I am aware the compiler produces terrible assembly for now - that is because i am currently focussing on ease of implementation, and saving the hard part for later. I dont want to concern myself with e.g. register allocation right now.

Comment: Hmm... Given that i got RSP wrong, how come this code appears to work now?

Comment: Update: It does indeed not work.